# Protobuf in compiled Unity build throws InvalidOperationException: No serializer defined for type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net for Unity to load data for a level. The serialization/deserialization works when running in the editor but when I compile and create a build then run it, I'm getting the following exception on deserialization:

```
InvalidOperationException: No serializer defined for type:
System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, 
    mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
```

I'm not 100% sure how protobuf-net analyses types before using them for deserialization so I'm not sure how to fix this issue. If anyone knows what could be causing this issue, I'd really appreciate an explanation. Is it possible for me to define the deserialization method myself? Something like a custom deserializer for a certain type? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is the class I believe to be causing the issue:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class LevelData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Background = "";
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name = "";
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Dictionary<string, int> PreloadInfo {get; private set;}
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public List<string> RoomFiles { get; private set; }

    public LevelData()
    {
        PreloadInfo = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        RoomFiles = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

After running protogen, I noticed that the version of String and Int32 don't match between Unity and the compiled dll I have created. Unity tries to deserialize with version 2.0.5.0 while my compiled dll uses version 2.0.0.0. I'm assuming this is why the deserialization fails. Here is the output from protogen:

```
Adding System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
  Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, msc
  orlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]...
  Adding System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Versi
  on=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, ms
  corlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]...
```

Code used to deserialize:

```
var serializer = GnomingSerializer.Create ();

int startMillis = System.Environment.TickCount;

TextAsset levelDoc = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(path);
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(levelDoc.bytes);

//LevelData levelData = Serializer.Deserialize<LevelData>(mStream);
LevelData levelData = new LevelData();
serializer.Deserialize (mStream, levelData, typeof(LevelData));
```

Comment: Would switching to something like protobuf-csharp-port help this situation? https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/

Comment: Are you using runtime processing? Or are you using the protogen tool? Basically : how could I reproduce it?

Comment: I am using runtime to serialize and deserialize the data. I'm also developing for the Wii U and this is only happening when I run it on the hardware so it may be something to do with the API subset provided by Unity on the hardware.

Comment: I'm on mobile, but i suggest using the precompiler here - search for "introducing protobuf-net precompiler protogen" or similar

Comment: No luck. I used the precompiler and switched up my code and I'm still getting the same exception. Is there any way I can force the precompiler to include a serializer for KeyValuePair?

Comment: are you perhaps using a dictionary as the object you are passing to serialize?

Comment: This is during deserialization, but yes. My classes use Dictionary to store information that is serialized. Should I be using something else? I'm using a ProtoContract and serializing an entire class, then deserializing in-game.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it sounds like the root type in your tree is a dictionary. During static analysis of the DTO assembly, it has no way to identify this - so doesn't consider the KVP scenarios (of which there are infinitely many). You can fix this without changing your existing code - just add something the analysis tool can find. For example, if you serialize a `Dictionary<string, MyType>` as the root object, just add:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class NeverUsed {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<string,MyType> Dummy;
}
```

(now re-run protogen etc)

That should be enough for the static analysis tool to find it and prepare a strategy that works for `KeyValuePair<string,MyType>`

The other approach is to always serialize your own types as the root of a model - essentially starting from a `NeverUsed` instance.

Comment: I have added an example class to my original post. I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by "the root type in your tree". Would you be able to clarify that a little bit? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Spencer by the "root type", I mean the thing would actually pass to Serialize, or the T/Type you pass to Deserialize. If that is LevelData, then what you have *should* work - can you confirm the output from protogen? And that you are referencing and using the output from protogen?

Comment: I'm using a program I wrote to generate the serialized data used in the game. I didn't use the protogen dll I generated to regenerate the serialized data. Could this be the issue I'm seeing? Would using the regular protobuf-net serialization cause problems when deserializing with a protogen dll?

Comment: @Spencer the data on the wire should be identical: all protogen does is move all the analysis to a fixed point in time (usually a build step) rather than runtime.

Comment: I have put an example of the protogen output in my original post.

Comment: @Spencer it looks like it is there - are you sure you are using the generated serializer? Unfortunately I don't have access to a computer for a few days (family holiday)

Comment: I am using the serializer I have generated (see original post, I have added how I am using it in one instance). Would the difference in runtime versions (.NET 2.0.0.0 and Unity 2.0.5.0) not be causing the issue?